# i need replace word in url using htaccess and redirect it

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to use .htaccess file to replace a word in URL

something like this:

example URL:

```
     http://domain.com/produts
```

redirect to:

```
    http://domain.com/digital-tiles
```

how can i do it any idea??

Answer (score 2):

That can be done in many ways as these:

```
Redirect 301 /products /digital-tiles
```

OR using `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/?$ /digital-tiles
```

OR using `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/?$ /digital-tiles [L,R=301,NC]
```